# Strong Markov property of Brownian motion on $[0,1]$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be standard Brownian motion with respect to filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq 0}$. Let $T$ be any stopping time. Is it true that $B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_T$, or is it true that $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|\,|\,\mathcal{F}_T]=\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|]$?

---

I am not sure whether $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is right continuous or not, but I know $B_t$ has continuous path and $B_{t\wedge 1}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale. When I search strong Markov property for Brownian motion, textbooks or other notes usually give me $B_{T+t}-B_T$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{T+}$ and they usually assume $P(T<\infty)>0$. I am not sure whether these regularity assumption is needed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|\,|\,\mathcal{F}_T]=\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|]$? If this is true then (since $(T>1) \in\mathcal F_T$) we get  $0=\mathbb{E} I_{T>1}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|=\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|]P(T>1)$ which is clearly false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KaviRamaMurthy. It seems we cannot directly remove $\mathcal{F}_T$, then do you think we can get rid of the conditional expectation by the following upper bounding process: $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|\,|\,\mathcal{F}_T]\leq 2\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|\,|\,\mathcal{F}_T]=2\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|]$?

Comment: The first inequality is fine but  the last step is wrong. You cannot get rid of the conditioning. @William

Comment: Thanks again @KaviRamaMurthy, I want to do that because I am trying to upper bounding the term $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|\,|\,\mathcal{F}_T]$ by a constant. Currently I know $\mathbb{E}[|B_1-B_{T\wedge 1}|]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|B_t|]$ can be bounded above by a constant. If the conditional expectation cannot be avoided, do you know any approach that I could try?